# Netflix Fails To Play On Firefox

Tags: firefox, netflix, drm

Netflix on the latest version of Firefox (69.0.1) fails to show content. No error code appears, so I am a bit clue less where I could be going wrong with it. Has anyone faced similar issue before?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Firefox (69.0.1) is Netflix-*capable* but you must enable DRM for Netflix. Thanks to itsfoss.com, [we have the steps](https://itsfoss.com/netflix-firefox-linux/).

- Open a Firefox tab and type `about:preferences#content` in the address bar.
- Look for the **Digital Rights Management (DRM) Content** field.
- Check the box in front of **Play DRM-controlled content**, which will download and  install the Widevine plugin from Google. This can take a while, depending on server load and your Internet connection throughput.
- Open a new tab in Firefox and type `about:addons` in the address bar.
- Confirm both the **Widevine** and **OpenH264** add-ons are installed with *Always Active* mode.
- Restart Firefox, and test Netflix.
- If Netflix fails, close Firefox, open a terminal window, and run `sudo apt install libavcodec-extra`. When that completes, retry Netflix in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do I need this nss update too as described here? https://silicophilic.com/watch-netflix-on-linux/

Comment: @Jayce Douglas Try without, see if it's needed/