# Widevine plugin crashes when attempting to play Netflix DRM content with firefox

Tags: firefox, netflix, drm

I've recently updated my 18.04 install to 20.04.1 and Netflix fails to play its DRM content using Firefox (at the latest 78.0.2). When attempting to play a video on the Netflix website I am taken to an error page with F7701-1003 and a yellow bar appears at the top of the page frame from firefox saying that the plugin crashed.  I took the [obvious steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1176094/81191) to enable DRM.

The kernel message log contained these lines after each time the plugin would crash:

```
[440489.660558] MainThread[364746]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fb9fed72335 sp 00007fffa457a790 error 6 in libxul.so[7fb9fce9e000+4b5b000]
[440489.660566] Code: 8b 0d f7 80 39 05 48 89 01 c7 04 25 00 00 00 00 47 02 00 00 e8 dc 51 13 fe 48 8d 05 3f c7 d3 03 48 8b 0d d6 80 39 05 48 89 01 <c7> 04 25 00 00 00 00 49 02 00 00 e8 bb 51 13 fe 48 8d 05 50 c7 d3
```

So it looks like the plugin is crashing in `libxul.so`. To see where, I installed the firefox debug package, and [using this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557756), ran in the bash shell the following (where `IP` and `MAPOFF` were taken from the kernel log message):

```
IP=0x00007fb9fed72335
MAPOFF=0x7fb9fce9e000
ADDR=$(python3 -c "print(hex($IP-$MAPOFF))")
addr2line -j .text -e /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so $ADDR
```

With the resulting output:

```
/build/firefox-k3d8Rk/firefox-78.0.2+build2/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/dist/include/mozilla/RefPtr.h:67
```

Looking at the [firefox source online](https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/file/e56adbbfe01c2443bae35e3d6f34867e36c3828e/mfbt/RefPtr.h#l67) (I didn't want to install the source package, I doubt ubuntu has patched this file) doesn't really help much.

I was thinking it could be a `seccomp` issue similar to [this one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1614535).  So I disabled all sandboxing why running with these environment variables set: `MOZ_DISABLE_CONTENT_SANDBOX=1 MOZ_DISABLE_GMP_SANDBOX=1`.  But that didn't help either.

I've tried attaching a `gdb` instance to the plugin container using [these instructions](https://mikeconley.ca/blog/2014/04/25/electrolysis-debugging-child-processes-of-content-for-make-benefit-glorious-browser-of-firefox/). And while I can attach to the plugin container, gdb never catches anything and eventually the plugin is terminated.  I'm wondering if this is due to some anti-debugging features in the widevine plugin (ie. the library thinks its being debugged and is intentionally crashing).

Then I used `strace` to log all syscalls from all processes of the firefox instance and found where the plugin container is crashing.  Here's a relevant snippet:

```
359684 execve("/usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container", ["/usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container", "/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/Media-Streaming-Sites/gmp-widevinecdm/4.10.1582.2", "359458", "true", "gmplugin"], 0x7f6598fb1000 /* 82 vars */ <unfinished ...>
... snip ...
359684 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/Media-Streaming-Sites/gmp-widevinecdm/4.10.1582.2/libwidevinecdm.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 15</home/user/.mozilla/firefox/Media-Streaming-Sites/gmp-widevinecdm/4.10.1582.2/libwidevinecdm.so>
359684 read(15</home/user/.mozilla/firefox/Media-Streaming-Sites/gmp-widevinecdm/4.10.1582.2/libwidevinecdm.so>, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\354\16l\0\0\0\0\0\270\23l\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\08\0\n\0@\0(\0'"..., 832) = 832
359684 pread64(15</home/user/.mozilla/firefox/Media-Streaming-Sites/gmp-widevinecdm/4.10.1582.2/libwidevinecdm.so>, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\354\16l\0\0\0\0\0\354\16l\0\0\0\0\0\354\16l\0\0\0\0\0000\2\0\0\0\0\0\0000\2\0\0"..., 560, 7081708) = 560
359684 fstat(15</home/user/.mozilla/firefox/Media-Streaming-Sites/gmp-widevinecdm/4.10.1582.2/libwidevinecdm.so>, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=7085500, ...}) = 0
359684 pread64(15</home/user/.mozilla/firefox/Media-Streaming-Sites/gmp-widevinecdm/4.10.1582.2/libwidevinecdm.so>, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\354\16l\0\0\0\0\0\354\16l"..., 560, 7081708) = 560
359684 mmap(NULL, 7082268, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 15</home/user/.mozilla/firefox/Media-Streaming-Sites/gmp-widevinecdm/4.10.1582.2/libwidevinecdm.so>, 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
359684 close(15</home/user/.mozilla/firefox/Media-Streaming-Sites/gmp-widevinecdm/4.10.1582.2/libwidevinecdm.so>) = 0
359684 --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=NULL} ---
359684 rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, NULL, {sa_handler=0x7fdf19dbc670, sa_mask=[ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE SEGV], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_ONSTACK|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fdf1db583c0}, 8) = 0
359684 write(7<pipe:[3459405]>, "`\0\0\0001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0MOZ_CRASH(aborting because of MsgProcessingError)\212\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\000359686:\"Chrome_ChildThread\",6\0\0\0X\0\0\0\0\0\0\0/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/Media-Streaming-Sites/gmp-widevinecdm/4.10.1582.2", 201) = 201
359684 close(7<pipe:[3459405]>)         = 0
359684 prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, SUID_DUMP_USER) = 0
```

So in the strace output we can see that the plugin container process is `359684`. It is successfully, opening the plugin library file and doing a `read` and a couple `pread64` successfully. Then tries to `mmap` the file, but fails and shortly there after the process gets a `SIGSEGV` with code `SEGV_MAPERR`.  The process's `SIGSEGV` handler is then invoked and an error message is written indicating there was a crash because of a `MsgProcessingError` in the library.

How can I fix this?

Comment: For information, there is a known issue and workaround with Widevine and the Firefox Apparmor profile: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1777070

Comment: That's only a solution if apparmor is the problem.  In my case it wasn't.  It was that the profile was on a special user mount which was mounting with the `noexec` property.

Comment: Ok, I found your question on a search engine when looking for a solution to my problem. So maybe my comment will help other users.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR;** Verify that the plugin is located on a mount that has execute permissions on.

It turns out the profile was located on a mount with the `noexec` property.  So a call to `mmap` with `PROT_EXEC` should fail with `EPERM` as it did. However, the library uses `mmap` to load its instructions into memory and then execute them.  Once the profile (and thus the plugin file) was moved to a mount with execute priviledges, streaming Netflix content works as expected.

Though I don't explicitly set `noexec` on any of my mounts, it was being implicitly added because `/home/user/.mozilla` is a mount point in `fstab` with the `user` property, allowing the mount to be done by my user.  The `user` property implicitly adds `noexec` to the mount.

I'm guessing that I was getting a [`SEGV_MAPERR`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000002/what-is-segv-maperr) because the code assumed that the `mmap` was successful and tried to run instructions in the mapped memory that was requested. However, since the `mmap` failed, that memory was not actually mapped.

The moral of the story is, if widevine is crashing and you do weird stuff with your profile locations, make sure the library is able to be executed.  This could all have been avoided by having widevine be a package that is installed next to the firefox binaries, but there's probably some legal reason for not doing so.

Comment: That helped me thinking. In my case (CentOS) it was SELinux.